# node bind and promise

Tags: node.js, promise, bind

I googled some bind explanation but still very confused. I am using bind with promise in the following way. It's working, but I don't know why. Hope someone could explain and help me with a small issue I got. Here is the sample code:

```
var temp1 = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve("hello");
    });
};

var temp2 = function(para1, para2){
    console.log("1:", para1);
    console.log("2:", para2)
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve(para1+" "+para2);
    });
};

temp1().then(temp2.bind(null,"world")).then(function(out){
   console.log(out); 
});
```

Output:

> 1: world \
>   2: hello \
>   world hello \

I use "bind" because it can make the code cleaner and easier for error handling, otherwise I have to use the following:

```
temp1().then(function(out1){
    return temp2(out1, "world").then(function(out2){
        console.log(out2);
    });
});
```

Besides how bind works, I have the following question:

```
temp1().then(temp2.bind(null,/*the second param is a property of the output from temp1*/)).then(function(out){
   console.log(out); 
});
```

I know I can always break the chain or add additional chain to achieve it:
for example

```
temp1().then(function(out1){
    return temp2(out1, (out1.length).to_String()).then(function(out2){
        console.log(out2);
    });
});
```

But it would be awesome not to break the chain.

So my two questions: 1. how bind works, 2. how to keep the chain(also no additional chain) while I can still access the previous output's properties in the params of next function inside then.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

So technically, `temp2.bind(null,"world")` will return a function and pass `null,"world"` as parameter. Then, those parameters are merged with the result of `temp1` which is `"hello"` at index `0`. Therefore, the actual parameters are passed to temp2 are `"hello", "world"`.

To keep the chain you can write:

```
temp1()
  .then(function (out) {
    return temp2(out,"world")
  })
  .then(function(out){
    console.log(out); 
  });
```

This is why people created Promise so that you can chain them nicely. The example you gave works but it is similar to Callback Hell.

Comment: Because according to definition the arguments are 'preceding any provided', the outcome is not "hello", "world", but rather "world", "hello". I still don't get why the arguments are not `null, "world", hello` though. The initial null seems to get eaten somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`bind()` is used to set the appropriate context for a function to be called later. I don't think you need to use it in this scenario. If you are using `es6` you can do something like so:

```
temp1()
    .then(out1 => temp2(out1, out1.length.toString()))
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log);
```

This uses an implicit return. This works because `temp2()` also returns a promsie so we can chain it to the next promise resolver